# Generic name for the operator $L = (I + \alpha U V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, reflection

I would like to know if there is a general name for the operator $ L = (I + \alpha U V)$. I encounter this in the Householder reflection, with $\alpha = -1$ and $V = U^T$, therefore  $H = (I - U U^T)$.

In general, $U$ and $V$ are vectors of the same dimension.

But in general does the above mentioned general operator $L$ have any specific names ?

Comment: I don't think there is a general name for this kind of matrix. If you are looking for keywords for a web search, try "perturbation of a matrix by a rank-one matrix"

Comment: Thanks. That helps!

Comment: It also is a special case of the Schur Complement.